# pushViewController is not changing the screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have this code to show a nib on click of row index

```
    UIViewController *controller = [[ShowFavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowFavViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"here");
```

but its not showing ShowFavViewController.xib file, although its showing "here" in log.
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but make sure you do a `[controller release]` after your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first bet would be that `self.navigationController` is `nil` (because the currently-displayed view controller is not a direct child of a navigation controller), or `controller` is `nil` (because there was an error during initialization).  Check both of those first.

Comment: Yes self.navigationController is nil. What to do now? How to achieve my desired functionality?

Comment: Do you, in fact, have a navigation controller on the screen?  Or do you just have a view controller with a navigation bar as part of the view?  You will have to use a UINavigationController as the direct parent of the view if you want to use self.navigationcontroller.  Otherwise, if you can access the navigation controller through some other object, do that.